# How do I connect my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to a hidden network? Nothing I've read works

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3b+

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

> I just installed Raspbian on my SD card, but I cannot connect to my
> network initially because it is hidden. I've tried following the guide
> https://raspi.tv/2017/how-to-auto-connect-your-raspberry-pi-to-a-hidden-ssid-wifi-network
> here (and the guide it links to). I've tried modifying my
> wpa_supplicant.conf to look like

```
ctr_interfaces=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
        ssid="My Network Name"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="secret_password"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        group=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        priority=1
        id_str="raspi"
}
```

etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Also, I can't make the network visible.

Comment: Can you connect a monitor and keyboard?

Comment: Unlikely to be a Pi specific problem.  Not being able to connect to a hidden (no broadcast ssid)  network is a common problem.

Comment: @goldilocks I can connect to a monitor and a keyboard.

Comment: You'll need a `bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` clause with the MAC address of the access point and `scan_ssid=1`. The simpler option is unhide the SSID. Hiding an SSID does precisely nothing to enhance WiFi security.

Comment: If you tried using normal Raspbian networking (preferably dhcpcd - but even obsolete Wheezy settings would work if you remove extraneous parameters) it would work.

Answer (score 0):

This presumes Raspbian 10 (buster).

First stop the system dhcpcd service:

```
sudo systemd stop dhcpcd
```

Check `wpa_supplicant` has stopped:

```
ps -C wpa_supplicant
```

If not, `kill` it.  Temporarily move `/etc/network/interfaces` and replace it with an empty file.

Then in one terminal (this will block if successful and produces output as it runs):

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This will run in the foreground and produce output comprehensible enough to tell whether it has succeeded or not.  If so, you can now (from another terminal)

```
sudo dhcpcd --nobackground
```

You should be able to see what's going on with the two components.

Note that normally, `dhcpcd` starts `wpa_supplicant`.  However, if it is already running (because you started it first, as above), a second instance will not start on the same interface.

Comment: Dhcpcd will NOT be running because the interfaces calls DHCP

Comment: @Milliways Dhcpcd is normally started by directly by systemd at boot (`dhcpcd.service`).  The stuff in `/etc/network` is just used by the commands `ifup` and `ifdown`, which are run by `networking.service`-- but only once at boot or when subsequently invoked (ie., that is *not* a persistent service; I think mostly what it is about is providing concrete criteria for `network-online.target`).  Other than being run in order if they are both running, one does not require the other, and while the networking service may make use of dhcpcd, dhcpcd does not make any use of the networking service...

Comment: ...If you stop the service and start `dhcpcd` manually, nothing in `/etc/networks` matters (actually, it is exactly the same if you start it via `systemd start dhcpcd`, but the manual foreground invocation above is simpler for debugging problems).  That said, to be paranoid, it might as well be emptied first (so edited).

Comment: dhcpcd is a DHCP client (among other things) If dhcpcd detects another active DHCP client it disables itself. There is a boot message to this effect if interfaces includes dhcp. All the OP has to do is pick a networking tool (anp properly configure it) rather than trying to mix incompatible tools (and not include random parameters). Mind you, the OP has provided no meaningful status information.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is.  The first instruction above is `sudo systemd stop dhcpcd`.  This will stop `dhcpcd` and it will not be running.  You can then invoke `sudo dhcpcd` manually.  There is no "trying to mix incompatible tools" here. *My* point is that *if* there is a problem beyond the system's control -- a reason why the normal services are *not* working -- this is a way to check for a significant subset of such reasons.

Comment: Can you run `sudo wpa_supplicant -d -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and see if the debug output gives you a clue (-dd gives more).  Do you have any odd characters in the password or SSID?  Do you know the channel used? Check you have no carriage returns in the file (line feeds only) Try stripping out all lines from proto to id_str inclusive - they should auto negotiate.  You could also try using wpa_passphrase to generate the file and add the ‘scan’ to the result using SUDO and nano as the editor.